# RPI dht22 with flask: Unable to set line 4 to input - Timed out waiting for PulseIn message

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, hardware

I'm trying to make a Raspberry Pi 3 REST API that provides temperature and humidity with DHT22. The whole code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from sds011 import SDS011
from adafruit_dht import DHT22
import board
import os
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
dht = DHT22(board.D4)

def get_dht_data():
    while True:
        try:
            temperature, humidity = dht.temperature, dht.humidity
            print(temperature, humidity)
            if temperature is not None and humidity is not None:
                return temperature, humidity
            else:
                raise
        except:
            time.sleep(0.5)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def status():
    temperature, humidity = get_dht_data()

    return jsonify({
        'temperature': temperature,
        'humidity': humidity
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I used https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_DHT

However, when I start server, it shows message

> 'Unable to set line 4 to input'

and temperature and humidity is always `None`. If I don't run flask app but just DHT code, it works.

Comment: Did an answer below solve your problem?

Comment: @BrienFoss Sorry for the very late reply. In the end I couldn't solve it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer

Remove `debug=True` and enjoy. :-)

#### What was going on?

This problem drove me nuts but I think I found the root cause! In my case, I was encapsulating the DHT22 object in another object, like so:

```
...
class DHT22Custom:
    def __init__(self):
        print("**** BUILDING by {0}!".format(threading.currentThread().getName()))
        self.dht_device = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D17)
...
```

My `main.py` looked like:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from sensor.config.app_config import create_app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()         # builds DHT22Custom inside
    app.run(debug=True)
    print("Cleaning up GPIO before exiting...")
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

And look what an interesting output I got:

```
root@05600e5:/app# python -m sensor.main
**** BUILDING by MainThread!
 * Serving Flask app "FlaskWS" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
**** BUILDING by MainThread!
Unable to set line 17 to input
```

The MainThread was initializing my object twice! How was that? Well, if you look at the documentation of Flask's `run()`, you'll see the following:

```
If the :attr:`debug` flag is set the server will automatically reload
 for code changes and show a debugger in case an exception happened.
```

So, it seems that Flask just relaunches the application or something like this. Not clear to me, to be honest. But well, if you just remove `debug`, you'll see something like:

```
root@05600e5:/app# python -m sensor.main
**** BUILDING by MainThread!
 * Serving Flask app "FlaskWS" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Locating the process `libgpiod_pulsein` and killing it resolved the issue.

In your terminal, search for the process ID:

`pgrep libgpiod_pulsein`

and

`kill <PID>` (found from above - you might have more than one running)

---

I was experiencing the exact same thing with the [DHT11](https://learn.adafruit.com/dht). In my situation I had to kill the process: `libgpiod_pulsein`.

Worked on the first try when on fresh boot, but then subsequent executions would fail. Changing the GPIO I was using and running the program had the same effect, worked the first time and subsequent attempts would fail with example:

> Unable to set line 4 to input
>
> Timed out waiting for PulseIn message
>
> Timed out waiting for PulseIn message
>   ...

Comment: In my case, `pgrep libgpiod_pulsein` returned nothing. But changing pin to `D18` solved the issue. Seems to me like something else is blocking GPIO4, but no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
> In my case, pgrep libgpiod_pulsein returned nothing. But changing pin to D18 solved the issue. Seems to me like something else is blocking GPIO4, but no idea what. – Slav Apr 4 at 18:03

thanks,with the pin 18 its ok

but it is strange:

The pin 4, only run it: (version deprecated of adafruit)> runing before:

sudo modprobe w1-gpio

sudo modprobe w1-therm

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT

while True:

    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11, 4)
    print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue with you meaning that using python, flask and cyrcuitpython adafruit_sht library I can only run once for every pin on rpi 4 the code. Finally the solution was in front of me and was the line `dhtDevice.exit()`

So before ending my code and return to the main class I run the command `dhtDevice.exit()`
so the next time I run the same code evrything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling 1-wire in the rasbian config resolved the issue for me.

`sudo raspi-config`

Select `3 Interface Options`, then `I7 1-Wire` and disable it by selecting `No` and rebooting the device.